# Make subsection visible in local TOC only, not in Main TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices, tocloft, etoc

I am writing a large **article** type document with a series of complex appendices in it.

I have included a local table of contents with each appendix that lists the sections and subsections within that specific appendix (the local TOC for Appendix A lists only that appendix's subsections, etc) using tools from the `etoc` package.

What I would like to do is have my appendix sections contain numbered subsections/subsubsections, but have the subsections/subsubsections only appear in the appendix local TOC. However I still want the appendix sections to appear in the main TOC.

Here is a rough approximation of my setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft} % Adds tools for TOC customization
\usepackage{etoc} % Local toc
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
  \tableofcontents

  \section{First section}
    \subsection{a Subsection}
  \section{Second section}
    \subsection{a Subsection}
    \subsection{Another Subsection}

  \begin{appendix}
    \section{Appendix A} % <- I want this to appear in the main TOC
      \etocsetnexttocdepth{2}
      \localtableofcontents
      \subsection{Appendix Subsection} % <- I want this to appear in the local TOC, but not the main TOC
  \end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: Sample output of demo LaTex with notes]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry, its loaded properly in my real document. This mockup is wrong. I'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an `\addtocontents` command to the main TOC reducing the `tocdepth`.  Since you're using the `etoc` package, this is done with the `\etocsettocdepth.toc` command. You then have to tell the local table of contents to ignore the current tocdepth and use its own. This is done with `\etocignoretoctocdepth`.  It seems easiest to put all of these commands at the beginning of the `appendix` environment. I've done this using the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft} % Adds tools for TOC customization
\usepackage{etoc} % Local toc
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendix}{\etocsettocdepth.toc{section}\etocignoretoctocdepth
\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsection}}

\begin{document}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
  \tableofcontents

  \section{First section}
    \subsection{a Subsection}
  \section{Second section}
    \subsection{a Subsection}
    \subsection{Another Subsection}

  \begin{appendix}
    \section{Appendix A} % <- I want this to appear in the main TOC
    \localtableofcontents
    \subsection{Appendix Subsection} % <- I want this to appear in the local TOC, but not the main TOC
  \end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

(It seems to me that `etoc` is a replacement for `tocloft` so I'm not sure if they should be used together, but I've left the package in your document.)

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work, but I may just be missing something. In your example output you also appear to have the heading for the 'Appendix Subsection' but not the local toc entry for it, is that correct?

Comment: @enpaul Sorry about that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That did it, except for some reason the first appendix still displayed the subsections in the main TOC. I reordered the appendices and the problem stayed with the first appendix. I verified your answer because it works in the sample test document just fine, there's just something in my document that's screwing with it.

Comment: @enpaul If you put the commands manually (not using the `AtBeginEnvironment` code), does it work?

Comment: If I put the line commands immediately before the first appendix's local TOC then it works perfectly, for both the first appendix and all the others.

Comment: @enpaul Strange. I can't reproduce that behaviour with the MWE.